# Loading jQuery qTip code dynamically

Tags: jquery, qtip

For an application I am writing, I have the need to dynamically load content into a DIV when a form is submitted.

This dynamically loaded content needs several tooltips to be displayed automatically at the time of loading (no need for an event to trigger it). I chose qTip because it has parameters to do this, unlike most other tooltips I found, which require an event to trigger the tooltip (like onmouseover).

This is the qTip code used to achieve this:

```
$(function(){
    $('#someelement').qtip({
        content: 'This is the message!',
        show: { ready: true, when: false },
        hide: { false },
        position: {
            corner: {
                target: 'topLeft',
                tooltip: 'bottomRight'
            }
        },
        style: {
                        ............ styling code here................
            }
        }
    })
});
```

This works fine in any shape or form that I try it. The tip successfully appears.

However, the tooltip does not appear if I am dynamically loading this code along with the content.

The content is being loaded using Malsup's great form and taconite plugins.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Of course, if you know of another method or plugin I could use to achieve the same similar effect, don't be shy to suggest it. :)

Comment: You say "the tooltip does not appear if I am dynamically loading this code along with the content". What is "this code"?

Comment: "This code" is the code you see above.

I am inserting text and HTML dynamically into a page. Along with the jquery code you see above in order to activate several tooltips within that text I am dynamically inserting.

It seems qTip is not aware of the dynamically inserted text and can not find the elements to apply the tool tips to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had this problem before and this is how I solved it. Put the plugin code inside a separate function and call that on document ready:

```
$(function(){
    loadQtip();
});

function loadQtip() {
    $('#someelement').qtip({
        content: 'This is the message!',
        show: { ready: true, when: false },
        hide: { false },
        position: {
            corner: {
                target: 'topLeft',
                tooltip: 'bottomRight'
            }
        },
        style: {
                        ............ styling code here................
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Then when you add in new data call the function again:

```
...
complete: function() {
    loadQtip();
}
```

You'll find for events such as click, change etc the `.live()` method works a treat, but when your setting a plugin to an element there isn't a persistent method.

Comment: I like your idea! I created a function, to which I can pass parameters. The parameters are basically the text for the tooltip, and the element that will have the tooltip.

I can then call this function from within taconite's EVAL commands, which basically what it does is execute jQuery code when I call the taconite plugin.

But... it seems qtip is still not aware of the dynamically inserted content. I can run my function, after the "ajax" call, and apply tooltips to many elements within the web site.

However, it seems qTip is not aware of the elements that I am dynamically inserting. :(

Comment: So basically, it seems qTip can not find in the DOM the elements I just inserted...