# .live and textarea auto-resizer

Tags: jquery, live

I am using small plugin to jquery:
[jquery-plugin-autoresize](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/jquery-plugin-autoresize/)

But i have trouble with using it with .live.

Does anyone know how to do it?

I tried

```
$('textarea .blog_comment').live('autoResize', function(e,{
// On resize:
onResize : function() {
$(this).css({opacity:0.8});
},
// After resize:
animateCallback : function() {
$(this).css({opacity:1});
},
// Quite slow animation:
animateDuration : 300,
// More extra space:
extraSpace : 40
}){});;
```

But it won't work.
Please help. Thank you/

Comment: In the answer below I changed your selector slightly, since a `<textarea>` can't have children I imagine the class is cirectly on it, or it's reversed, e.g. `.blog_comment textarea`, I'm not sure which.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either need to re-run the plugin after your elements are ready again, e.g. in the `success` handler of whichever AJAX method you're using, like this:

```
$.ajax({
   //options
   success: function(data) {
     $('textarea.blog_comment').autoresize({...plugin options...});
   }
});
```

Or use a plugin like [`.livequery()`](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/livequery/), like this:

```
$('textarea.blog_comment').livequery(function() {
  $(this).autoResize({
    onResize : function() {
      $(this).css({opacity:0.8});
    },
    animateCallback : function() {
      $(this).css({opacity:1});
    },
    animateDuration : 300,
    extraSpace : 40
  });
});
```

The short version is that [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) doesn't work for this...it's event driven, so not really suited for running most plugins.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question [can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456442/loading-jquery-qtip-code-dynamically/3456475#3456475):

[Loading jQuery qTip code dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456442/loading-jquery-qtip-code-dynamically/3456475#3456475)

Comment: That same approach doesn't work here...it'd re-run the plugin for every element, even if it's already run, a situation you're not in with IDs :)

Comment: Fair point Nick, will have to check out the livequery plugin :-)